# Google Places API "types" issue

Tags: web-services, google-places-api, google-places

I was used to getting datas from google places web service. But, This week I realize that web service link: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=41.025414,29.114866&radius=5000&types=gas_station&sensor=true&key=XXXXXXXXX is returning "ZERO_RESULTS". It was used to return 50 places and I did not change anything on code.

When I remove types=gas_stations, it is working well. So, do you have any idea why "types" is not working well like it used to be?

Comment: In your question, you show the `types` parameter in the URL as: `gas_station` but then when you are talking about removing the parameter, you have: `types=gas_stations` (with an 's' at the end). Which one are you using in your code?

Comment: My mistake, it was type=gas_station.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you would have ever received 50 results as the Places API can only return 20 establishments at a time.

I would suggest trying the parameter `types=gas_station` at a multiple locations to make sure that is not working correctly, after which if you are still not receiving any results I would suggest filing this issue on the [Google Places API Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Bug).

A temporary solution would be to use the `keyword=gas station` parameter. This appears to return relevant results.